# Remove comma at start of string

Tags: jquery

Campaign Monitor has a script that outputs your campaign archive.
This is the output:

```
<article class="node history">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://xxx.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/x/1448CC2F5A9BABD9/C67FD2F38AC4859C/" class="ext">Title</a>, 04 July 2012</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Because I want to separate the date from the title (by giving the a-element a certain width); how can I get rid of the comma and space that's in front of the date - using jQuery?

When I try this next bit of code, my a-element within the li-element disappears (so no more link, everything is just plain text).

UPDATE: okay, so this works for the comma. How to remove the space as well?

```
$(".node.history ul li").each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/[,]/, ""));
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, you need to fix your selector, and use `$().html()` instead of `$().text()`.

Your regex also doesn't want the square brackets - these define a set of characters to match (in your case one character that is either a comma or a space when you want [I think] comma *followed by* space). Full solution:

```html
<ul class="node history"> 
    <li>
        <a href=http://xxx.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/x/1448CC2F5A9BABD9/C67FD2F38AC4859C/ class="ext">Title</a>, 04 July 2012
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$("ul.node.history li").each(function() {
    var result = $(this).html().replace(/, /, "");
    $(this).html(result);
    alert(result);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/H5Hcj/

Comment: Thanks Richard, this seems to do the trick (with the right markup, that is).

Answer (score 1):

use `$.html()` instead of `$.text()`

Answer (score 1):

this may remove  the commas before the character

```
  $("ul.node.history li").each(function() {
 $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\,/g, ""));
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, try simple change your html string to:

```
<article class="node history">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://xxx.createsend.com/t/ViewEmailArchive/x/1448CC2F5A9BABD9/C67FD2F38AC4859C/" class="ext">Title</a>&nbsp 04 July 2012</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Remove comma and add '&nbsp' (white space)